# My batch file that runs other batch file won't wait before the first is finished (using /WAIT command). Can anyone help me do it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that runs 8 different batch files(these run for 20 hours). This is my batch file:

This one is named RUN_THIS_BATCH.bat

```
cd %cd%\Algo_gen_homme1-8
start   "1" x_homme1\homme1.bat
start   "2" x_homme2\homme2.bat
start   "3" x_homme3\homme3.bat
start   "4" x_homme4\homme4.bat
start   "5" x_homme5\homme5.bat
start   "6" x_homme6\homme6.bat
start   "7" x_homme7\homme7.bat
start   "8" x_homme8\homme8.bat
exit
```

This file works, but since it runs for a long time and I got many runs of 8 batches to do, I want to be able to continue the process over the weekend. So what I want to do is a batch that will wait for this one to finish before starting another one (which will run 8 others) and so on.

I tried using the /WAIT command but it doesn't work. All of the 16 batches start right when I run it. This is what I have in the main batch:

```
@echo off
start /WAIT "1-8" "Algo_gen_homme1-8\RUN_THIS_BATCH.bat" 
start /WAIT "9-16" "Algo_gen_homme9-16\RUN_THIS_BATCH.bat" 
exit
```

This one is for testing with 2 files, but my goal is to run 4 of them one after the other.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this post on [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4706#p27096)

Comment: Or this one on [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5598#p34476) as well.

Comment: Did you try running each of the scripts using `Call` instead of `Start`?